# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: php, docker, symfony, doctrine

I'm making a website with Symfony and I'm using Docker. I'm using the Dockerfiles coming from the dunglas/symfony-docker project on GitHub. https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/

When I'm launching my containers with `docker-compose up`, everything seems to be working fine. But when I'm trying to make a migration with `php bin/console make:migration`, I'm getting this error message :

`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: Name or service not known`

Does anyone know how I could fix it ? I'm not good at debugging networking issues with Docker. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` :

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    links:
      - database
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        SKELETON: ${SKELETON:-symfony/skeleton}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - ./:/srv/app:consistent
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      # Run "composer require symfony/orm-pack" to install and configure Doctrine ORM
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}
      MAILER_DSN: null://null
      APP_ENV: dev
      # Run "composer require symfony/mercure-bundle" to install and configure the Mercure integration
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp

# Mercure is installed as a Caddy module, prevent the Flex recipe from installing another service
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

I've tried putting the "database" container in the same network than the "caddy" and "php" containers but it doesn't seem to changing anything. Thanks a lot in advance if you can help me with this.

Comment: Make sure to run `php bin/console make:migration` from **INSIDE** the `php` Docker container (not on your host machine).

Try `docker-compose exec php sh -c 'bin/console make:migration'`.